# how to :hover but :not for :first-child of element?

Tags: css

I tried to get rid of hover for the first child of a element, but no advanced. Pls, could u help me with that. This code that I was attempting to adjust, but hopeless.

```
HTML

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navs-header">
                    <li style="color: white!important;"><a>Меню</a></li>
                    <?php if (Yii::$app->keyStorage->get('prolongation_enabled')): ?>
                        <li><a href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('/site/prolongation'); ?>">Пролонгация</a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if (Yii::$app->keyStorage->get('shop_enabled')): ?>
                        <li><a href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('/site/shop'); ?>"> Интернет - магазин</a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <li><a href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('/site/about'); ?>">О ломбарде</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('/site/services'); ?>">Наши услуги </a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('/site/news'); ?>">Новости </a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::toRoute('/site/contacts'); ?>">Связаться с нами</a></li>
                </ul>



  SAAS

 .navs-right {
    li{
      border-top: solid 1px #b8b8b8;
    &:first-child{
      background-color:  #fbce00;
      color: white!important;
      font: 17px $fontFamilyAvBold!important;
    }
      a{
        font: $font17Size-Regularfamily;
        padding: 15px 30px!important;

        &:not(:first-child):hover{
          color: #fbad30!important;
          font: 17px $fontFamilyAvBold!important;
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

Comment: The selector seems to be working.

Comment: Maybe you have a problem with specificity, do you have a codepen with all the involved code to make easier debugging it?

Comment: @JesusLugo I added whole code with html. Could u review

Comment: Can you show the parsed HTML and CSS and not PHP and SCSS, by the looks of it it should be working. There might be something else going on

Comment: Done analyzed, fixed... check my answer down here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for posting the code, the ideal option would be using an external site like codepen.io for that; and for us it is easier reading output code instead of PHP (I'm quite used to SCSS). On the other hand, the class `.navs-right` in the CSS is not present on the markup.

As far as I can see, the issue is that inside the markup, every link is `:first-child` (inside each `<li>` tag), so you need to use the first child of the parent, for this case, the output code should be something like:

```
 .navbar-right li:not(:first-child) a:hover {
   color: #fbad30!important;
   font: 17px $fontFamilyAvBold!important;
 }
```

That should make it work. You can see results here https://codepen.io/jelur/pen/WZpbNP

Now, additional comments on the code:

- If you want for a link to have padding (or margin) you need to use `display: inline-block` (or block).
- I'd recommend you against the excessive use of `!important`

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your `a` in a container like this:

```css
.hvr a:not(:first-child):hover { 
   color: #fbad30!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="hvr">
<a href="#">Link Text 1</a>
<a href="#">Link Text 2</a>
</div>
```